# How to add a progress bar to a package function in r

Tags: r, progress-bar

I am running a moving window function from the package landscapemetrics. This seems to take some time as the raster is quite big. It would be really helpful to have a progress bar or something similar. How can I code something like this without having a for loop or a self-coded function to begin with? I don't know how to provide an example raster, but here is my code:

```
my.raster <- raster('forest2_nonforest1_min_extent.tif')

#specify window size
moving_window <- matrix(1,nrow=5,ncol=5)

#moving window analysis
tt <- window_lsm(my.raster,
                   window = moving_window,
                   level= "landscape",
                   what = c("lsm_l_ed"))
```

I need to have a visualization of the progress for the last function (#moving window analysis)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The function `window_lsm()` uses `raster::focal()` internally, which doesn't provide a progress bar itself. So without writing your own loop/moving window function I think this won't be possible, unfortunately.

As already mentioned above, the progress argument in `window_lsm()` refers to layers and metrics only, but not the moving window.

Answer (score 0):

Not familiar with this package, but [`window_lsm()`](https://r-spatialecology.github.io/landscapemetrics/reference/window_lsm.html) has an argument `progress` which will "print progress report" when `TRUE`.

Otherwise, to the best of my knowledge it's not possible to implement a true progress bar without any kind of iteration / loop. The one other option I see would be to look at the source of `window_lsm()`; find the outermost loop (if there is one); define your own local version of the function; and insert a progress bar incremented inside the loop (e.g. using the [`progress`](https://github.com/r-lib/progress) package). (Obviously, you wouldn't want to redistribute this without looking into the licensing / discussing with package devs.)

I guess another option would be to somehow develop an estimate of how long the operation might take, e.g., based on the size of your  raster, then run a countdown timer in a parallel process? My hunch is this would be hard to implement and not especially accurate.

Comment: True window_lsm() has a progress report but it just shows how many layers are done, as I am only running one it does not really help. I already had the feeling its not easy. Thanks for the infos.